# C++11 Proper Structure Initialization

Tags: c++, c++11

Having a structure like this in C++11:

```
struct von
{
    std::string Name;
    unsigned int ID;
    std::vector<std::string> Checks;
};
```

Should it be initialized like this:

```
    von v = {"",0,{}};
```

Or like this:

```
    von v = {};
```

Both ways seem to work, but the compiler warns about `-Wmissing-field-initializers` on the latter example.

**Edit:**
Here are my compiler options:

```
g++ main.cpp -ansi -Wall -Wextra -Weffc++ -std=c++0x
```

I'm using g++ (Debian 4.6.2-12) 4.6.2

Comment: There are no initializer lists in your example, only list initialization. The best way might be `von v{};`.

Comment: von v{}; also complains of missing initializers for the members. It's a -Wmissing-field-initializer warning.

Comment: Hm, you're right. It's a shame you can't value-initialize an automatic variable... `von v{{},0,{}};` is the next-best thing.

Comment: Please make your title describe the question.

Comment: In the case of zero arguments, I personally think the warning from `-Wmissing-field-initializer` is overly pedantic.

Comment: @StilesCrisis Agreed, but not only then, also in the case of a single value of 0.

Comment: I have g++ 4.6.2, with no support for C11. Your code compiles without a warning with `g++ -Wall -pedantic --std=c++0x`. What compiler and command line options are you using?

Comment: Warning for the empty initializer list case is a false positive [that has been fixed](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61489).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't require initializer_list at all and work perfectly fine with C++03. Edit: (Ok, for the initialization of the vector you need C++11) In a struct or array initialization, all not explicitly given values are zero-initialized, so if that's what you want = {}; will work just fine.